# Query network device to determine operating system, without installing a remote agent?

Tags: python

I would like to query a device (e.g. an Android phone on WiFi) to find out what Operating System it is running, without having to run anything on the device or install an additional agent?

Is this possible?

Comment: Lets say an Android phone that is connected to my network over WI-fi

Comment: Con you explain more on: *"... without having to run the script ..."* part?

Comment: I don't want to have to run the script on the target, just run the script on my pc and query the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up phrases like "port scan" and "port mapping" for some ideas.  You'll need to make use of whatever services are already running on the target machine, which could include Avahi/Bonjour/mDNS, HTTP, SSH, SMTP, etc.  You'd try to figure out what ports might be open, try to connect there (or send UDP datagrams), and see what you find.  You could develop your own heuristics if you have enough devices or a small enough set you need to support, or you could probably find some existing code to do some of this (maybe not in Python directly though).